# Allow css through htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Earlier I made a question about creating seo friendly urls. And I got the answer.

Now I have a new problem. When I'm using mod_rewrite in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

to create link like: www.myurl.com/page/11

It's working fine. But when im entering the new page with the new lovely URL, I'm not getting any CSS.

I think my .htaccess doesn't allow it. How do I allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have cool URLs, you need to link your CSS/JS and image files from HTML with leading slash (`/`).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/web.js"></script>
```

Comment: This did the job :o) 

And now when I'm looking at it, I see why.. It's getting a new URL ofc. And then, yeah, I get it ;o) 

Thanks!

Comment: I will :o) Just waiting for the countdown to be.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at the html page source how the CSS files are referenced. When rewriting URLs to something like `/page/11` then for the browser it looks like you are using directories.

So, if your CSS files are referenced like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
```

then the browser looks for `/page/css/stylesheet.css` which of course does not exist.

To solve this, either add a rewrite rule for your CSS files to "undo" the path or change the reference to the CSS files to an absolute path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesheet.css" />
```